# How to execute project binaries in dynamically in Java

Tags: java, maven, testng

I have a maven project.it contains **TestNG** xml files in my specific folder.`(src/taget/myfiles)`.every build i collect the binaries for the project as a jar. let say i collect 3 binaries from the project that contains updated TestNG.xml file versions.

Eg:

**version 1.jar**

```
 mytest.xml version 1
```

**version 2.jar**

```
 mytest.xml version 2
```

**version 3.jar**

```
mytest.xml version 3
```

my requirement is that when i select the specific project binaries let say i select some older `version 2` instead of latest `version 3` when program runs it should pick the `mytest.xml V2` files from my `version 2.jar`.Actually i dont have much idea about this if anyone knows please let me know.

Comment: How is the number derived in your current setup?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen let say latest version is 4 actually it is in `src/target folder` physically in the eclipse.

Comment: So you DON'T use numbers, you just work on whatever was compiled by maven?

Comment: i use numbers like this myproject-15.1-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that when you collect your test-binary you install it with a specific version in your maven repository. Lets say app-test-1.0.0-V1-SNAPSHOT or whatever versioning you prefer. When you execute you retrieve this artifact by just manipulating the V1/V2/V3 version part and run it.

Comment: yes i do the same way i use maven nexus to store binaries.but my requirement is how can i run against selected project binaries.(some older binary)

Comment: One way could be to not get the binaries but the source artifact and unpackage it and simply run the "mvn test"

Comment: do you have any idea how can do it in programmatically.

Comment: You know of build servers like Jenkins?

Comment: In maven there are tasks to unpackage artifacts so i think everything you need is doable with mvn.